How to implement a searchable select using shadcn
I need a component, where the dropdown only shows when something has been typed into the input. Similar to mantine searchable select but using shadcn. Same way you type into google searchbar before the dropdown shows
     <Command>
          <CommandInput
            value={value}
            placeholder="Search framework..."
            onValueChange={(e) => {
              setValue(e);
              setOpen(true);
            }}
          />
          {open && value.trim() !== '' && (
            <CommandList>
              <CommandEmpty>No framework found.</CommandEmpty>
              <CommandGroup>
                {data.map((item) => (
                  <CommandItem
                    key={item.name}
                    value={item.name}
                    onSelect={(currentValue) => {
                      setValue(currentValue);
                      setOpen(false);
                    }}
                  >
                    <Check
                      className={cn(
                        'mr-2 h-4 w-4',
                        value === item.name ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'
                      )}
                    />
                    {item.name}
                  </CommandItem>
                ))}
              </CommandGroup>
            </CommandList>
          )}
        </Command>

